# gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

```
public class Epoch.MainWindow : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
    private Gtk.Grid grid;
    
    private Epoch.LabelsGrid labels;
    private Epoch.PreferencesView preferences_view;
    private Epoch.MainView main_view;
    
    public MainWindow (Application app) {
        Object (
            application: app,
            icon_name: "com.github.Suzie97.epoch",
            resizable: false,
            title: _("Epoch"),
            width_request: 500
        );
    }
    
    construct {
        get_style_context ().add_class ("rounded");
        set_keep_below (true);
        stick ();
        
        var preferences_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name ("open-menu-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR);
        preferences_button.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        
        var preferences_stack = new Gtk.Stack ();
        preferences_stack.add (preferences_view);
        preferences_stack.add (main_view);
        preferences_stack.transition_type = Gtk.StackTransitionType.SLIDE_LEFT;
        
        var headerbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar ();
        headerbar.show_close_button = true;
        
        var headerbar_style_context = headerbar.get_style_context ();
        headerbar_style_context.add_class ("default-decoration");
        headerbar_style_context.add_class (Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_FLAT);
        
        headerbar.pack_end (preferences_button);
        
        set_titlebar (headerbar);
        
        var main_box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
        main_box.pack_start (preferences_stack, true, true);
        add (main_box);
        
        show_all ();
        
        preferences_view = new Epoch.PreferencesView ();
        
        preferences_button.activate.connect (() => {
                preferences_stack.visible_child = preferences_view;
        });
        
    //     public override bool configure_event (Gdk.EventConfigure event) {
    //     int root_x, root_y;
    //     get_position (out root_x, out root_y);
    //     Epoch.settings.set_int ("window-x", root_x);
    //     Epoch.settings.set_int ("window-y", root_y);

    //     return base.configure_event (event);
    }
}
```

The following error is displayed when I compile,
[image]

I want the app to switch to the preferences view when the button on the right side of the header bar is clicked, [image]

Only, the headerbar is displayed when as you can see.

Why is this happening? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preferences_stack.add (preferences_view);
preferences_stack.add (main_view);
```

You haven't initialized `preferences_view` yet, and you never initialize `main_view`. That's where your second and third errors are coming from: `gtk_container_add()` is complaining that the widget you are trying to add is not actually a widget, but rather `null`, because you haven't initialized that variable yet.